# Value passed NULL from a View to another in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

In a view `Index`, I have a DropDownList `Gamme`. I define its item selected in my view, like this :

```
public string SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }
```

In this view, I have a button `Appliquer`that took me to another view `Application`.

```
<input type="button" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" onclick="window.location = 'ProfileGa/Application'"/>
```

In the view `Application`, I have a button submit `Appliquer`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Appliquer" id="appl"   />
```

When I click on `Appliquer`, I want save the value selected in my DropDownList `Gamme` in my base.

The problem is that this value is passed `NULL` when i change the view (exit page Index and open Application).

I find that with Debugging.

The Controller action :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult app(FlowViewModel model)
        {

            Famille fam = new Famille();

            fam.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
            db.Familles.Add(fam);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Application");

        }
```

***Note :***

I didn't forget this in the `Application`:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("app", "ProfileGa")) { %>
```

`ProfileGa` is the name of my controller.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your dropdown is in the `Index` view, and the selection is happening there. Then you're redirecting to `ProfileGa/Application` and leaving this information behind.

I would change this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Appliquer" .. etc
```

to a `<submit>`, and wrap the code with the dropdown in one of these:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Application", "ProfileGa")) {
```

and add a `Post` version of `Application`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Application(FlowViewModel model)
{
    // Do whatever
    return View(model);
}
```

Then when you get to the `Application` view, it should still have the same information as it left `Index` with.

To check this is working, put a breakpoint at `return View(model);` and look at the model's contents.

However, posting `null` *from* the view probably means that something is wrong inside your `<% using (Html.BeginForm("app", "ProfileGa")) { %>` statement, so if the above doesn't do anything, post the code from your `Application' view.

Comment: thx for the answer, I change the button like this :
`<input type="submit" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" onclick="window.location = 'ProfileGa/Application'"/>`
ani I wrap my DropDownlist like this :
`<% using (Html.BeginForm("Application", "ProfileGa"))
     {%>
  <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"), new { @id = "gg" })%> 
  <% } %>`
also i change the action like you mentionne above but when I execute , the button became static and do nothing when i click

Comment: No, I meant without the onclick. The `using` directive tells it where to go.

Comment: Yes I try it also without onclick and same result, is that true what i did to the dropdownlist